# I have just written 'hello world' program(C++) in VS Code but it shows error

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: It's a screenshot of my code as well as the corresponding error.]
Whenever I open a folder and create a file using VS code in c++ and run it, it generates an error(even when my code is completely correct). I can not understand what is the error. I have tried to change the location of folders but it does not resolved the issue. I am getting the same error everytime. Though when I write code in a file, it works but in folders, it does not work. I am dropping the screenshot of my code as well as the corresponding error. I think it has some issue related with path but I don't know how to resolve it, nor googling helped.
thanks already!

Comment: do you really think you are the first to have the `WinMain` error with C++, it is a recurring error almost every week and sometimes every day, most unlikely you can't find a related question here on SO, maybe because most post images of the error instead of the text

Comment: @rioV8 So you are saying that it happens by itself and there is no defined solution for it? If you know something, please tell. I will try that.

Comment: no I'm saying you haven't done the search, I have seen this question at least 20 times here on SO most of them posted an image of the problem